# InvalidUserName in asp.net CreateUser when creating a user with . character before the @ character

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I looked up the msdn documentation and it says that InvalidUserName is thrown when it does not find the username in the database, which is fine because the user I am creating should not exist in the database.

If I use test@example.com, it works, but if I try it with test.@example.com, the status from Membership.CreateUser is InvalidUserName.

Comment: How about test.somethingelse@example.com? I don't think that text.example.com IS a valid email address. I think both the dot (.) and the at (@) sign have special meaning in email addresses, and you need some non special character in between them. (I could be wrong, but I've never seen an email address set up like that.)

Comment: test.somethingelse@example.com works, but if I have a . before the @, it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Email addresses come in the form username@domain where domain is at least two parts separated by a period/dot.

The RFC Specification says that a . in the username part of the address **(the part before @)** is valid unless the . is the first or last character (of the username), so the behaviour that you are noticing is correct.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322

Good find @David Stratton: From the wikipedia link in his comment...

> Character . (dot, period, full stop)
> provided that it is not the first or
> last character, and provided also that
> it does not appear two or more times
> consecutively (e.g.
> John..Doe@example.com).

Comment: so test.@test should be valid.  Maybe this an asp.net Bug.

Comment: No, the username part of your email address (test.) ends in a dot, which is invalid.

Comment: No, it is NOT valid.  The username part is ALL the text before the @.  In your example, the . is the LAST part of the Username part, which, clearly, makes your example not a valid email address.

Here's an easier read than the one provided...  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_address

Comment: +1.  Thank you for finding the specification.  I hada feeling it was not correct, but didn't have time to look for the spec.

Comment: Thanks for the help to you both.  When you said the . character can't be at the beginning or end, I thought you meant at the end of the whole e-mail address.